# Custom IonicModal not hide at right position

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have made my custom ionicModal Popup by change the width and height. However I got problems to handle the right position when the modal hide. See my snippet for more clear.

My expected output will be ionicModal hide at bottom to '0' regardless of modal size.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',['ionic','ngCordova']);
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl',function($scope, $ionicModal){
  
       $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
             scope: $scope,
             animation: 'slide-in-up'
     }).then(function(modal) {
     $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  
  
  $scope.openModal = function() {
     $scope.modal.show();
  };
  
  $scope.home = function ()
  {
    $scope.modal.hide();
    }
});
```

```css
body
{
  background-color:#f3f3f3;
  }
.modalEduLevel
{
    width: 90%; 
    height: 80%; 
    min-height: 0; 
    max-height: 250px; 
    top: 20%; 
    left: 5%; 
    right: 5%; 
    bottom: 20%;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid gold;
}
.bg-gold
{
    background-color: #ffd70080;
}
.button-level
{
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    color: purple;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.button-level:hover, .button-level:active
{
    background-color: purple;
    color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-cordova/0.1.27-alpha/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-modal-view class="modalEduLevel">
    <ion-pane class="padding bg-gold">
        Select your education level
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
            Level 1
        </button>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
            Level 2
        </button>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
            Level 3
        </button>
    </ion-pane>
</ion-modal-view>
</script>
<button ng-click="openModal()">Open</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you can do it with setting this simple CSS declaration:

```
.slide-in-up.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 500%, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 500%, 0px);
}
```

Ionic sets the `ng-leave` class to every element that gets removed/hidden etc. The default transform for `slide-in-up` with `ng-leave` is `transform: translate3d(0px, 100%, 0px);` which is the same as when it enters `ng-enter`. By setting this to 500% it will be surely removed all the way to the bottom. You can do this same with the `ng-enter` class if you would like the animation to be similar in both cases. You can also overwrite the transition timing if you wish with a declaration like this:

```
.slide-in-up.ng-leave, .slide-in-up > .ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 450ms;
  transition: all ease-in-out 450ms;
}
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });


  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.home = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.modalEduLevel {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 250px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}
.slide-in-up.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 500%, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 500%, 0px);
}
.bg-gold {
  background-color: #ffd70080;
}
.button-level {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  color: purple;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.button-level:hover,
.button-level:active {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-cordova/0.1.27-alpha/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-modal-view class="modalEduLevel">
      <ion-pane class="padding bg-gold">
        Select your education level
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
          Level 1
        </button>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
          Level 2
        </button>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
          Level 3
        </button>
      </ion-pane>
    </ion-modal-view>
  </script>
  <button ng-click="openModal()">Open</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a demo for you of a custom slide function in the modal.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'custom-slide'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });


  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.home = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.modalEduLevel {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 250px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}
.bg-gold {
  background-color: #ffd70080;
}
.button-level {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  color: purple;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.button-level:hover,
.button-level:active {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white !important;
}
.custom-slide {
  top: 100% !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
.custom-slide.ng-enter-active {
  top: 20% !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out, top 350ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
.custom-slide.ng-leave {
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 450ms ease-in-out, top 350ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
.custom-slide.ng-leave .button-level:hover,
.custom-slide.ng-leave .button-level:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-cordova/0.1.27-alpha/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-modal-view class="modalEduLevel">
      <ion-pane class="padding bg-gold">
        Select your education level
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
          Level 1
        </button>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
          Level 2
        </button>
        <button ng-click="home()" class="button button-block button-level">
          Level 3
        </button>
      </ion-pane>
    </ion-modal-view>
  </script>
  <button ng-click="openModal()">Open</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why there are default settings and styles for these things. This is an basic example to change how it behaves but of course you could do a totally custom modal or use a plugin for them. This would require more work though. You could also set the `animation: 'slide-in-up'` to be what ever you would like and make your own CSS animation for it.

Comment: Ok..by the way I got your points. If anyone knows how to do that, it safe my time. Thanks.

Comment: @Imran I edited my answer and included a simple demo of a custom slide animation.